# クラスの関数で、self 以外の変数が何なのか分からない

Tags: python

Python初心者です。以下は参考書「独学プログラマー（コーリ・アリソフ著）」に記載されているWarというカードゲームのプログラムの一部です。その部分でわからないところがあるので質問させていただきます。

```
class Card:
    suits = ["spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"]

    values = [None, None, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
              "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]

    def __init__(self, v, s):
        """スートも値も整数値です。"""
        self.value = v
        self.suit = s

    def __lt__(self, c2):
        if self.value < c2.value:
            return True

        if self.value == c2.value:
            if self.suit < c2.suit:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        return False
```

#### 質問

`def __lt__(self. c2)`の部分で`c2.value`や`c2.suit`というところがありますが。何の値が入っている変数なのかよくわかりません。どなたかよろしくお願いします。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　参考書からのプログラムということですが、引用の要件を満たすため、どの参考書から持ってきたものなのかを追記して頂けませんか？　質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！これからたくさん質問させていただきますのでよろしくお願いします！参考書については早速、記載させていただきました。

Comment: タイトルだけで質問内容が分かりやすくなるよう、タイトルがご質問の内容を具体的に表すよう編集したいのですが、今回のご質問の趣旨は「クラスの関数で、self 以外の変数が何なのか分からない」ということで良いでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！質問がわかりにくいのに噛み砕いていただいてありがとうございます！かなりピン！ときました！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python ではクラスに `__lt__` という名前のメソッドを定義することで、クラスのインスタンス同士を不等号 `<` 等で比較できるようになります。メソッド `__lt__` には 2 つの引数が渡されることになりますが、一方が自分で、他方が比較される相手です。

今回の `__lt__` にも 2 つの引数 `self` と `c2` があり、どちらも `Card` クラスのインスタンスであることが期待されています。第一引数の `self` は自分自身であり、第二引数の `c2` は比較相手です。ですから `c2.value` や `c2.suit` というのは、比較相手の番号やスートのことを指しています。

試しに `Card` クラスのインスタンスを作って比較してみると分かりやすいです。

```
>>> c1 = Card(4, 1)
>>> c2 = Card(5, 2)
>>> c1 < c2
True
```

より詳しくは、Python 3 の公式ドキュメントにおける [`object.__lt__(self, other)` の説明](https://docs.python.jp/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)が参考になります。

Comment: その書籍の翻訳者です。 `__lt__` の引数は、174,175ページに登場する `__add__` と同じように、演算子（+や<）の右に登場するものが引数に渡ってきます。動きが分かるサンプルとしてPython Tutorにコードを置いたので見てみてください https://goo.gl/vPwJKY のページで "Forward"ボタンを押して動きを確認できます

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます！！まさか翻訳者の方からご連絡いただけるとは思ってなかったのでうれしいです！参考にさせていただきます！