# 以下のコードでreturnの返してくる値がなぜそうなるのかわからない。

Tags: python, python3

`def __lt__`のメソッドで条件に応じて`True`または`False`を返してくるようにしていますが、メソッドの最後の行に`return False`があるので結局すべて`False`で返ってきてしまうと思いました。ただ、条件文にしたがって正しく返してくれるのですがそれがなぜなのかと、このコードの必要性が理解できないです。

```
class Para:
    def __init__(self, para1):
        self.para1 = para1

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.para1 < other.para1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        return False   #このリターンを書く意味がわからない。

para1 = Para(1)
para2 = Para(2)
print(para1 < para2)
print(para1 > para2)

>>>True
>>>False
```

Comment: もしコードが第三者の書いたサンプルや参考書のものであるなら、その事を明記しておいた方がよいと思います。言語の仕様に従っているなら、コードの意図は書いた本人にしか分かりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おっしゃるとおりで、今回のコードにおいて当該の `return False` に到達することはありません。Dead code になっています。動作を考える限りは、この行は不要です (あるいは、else 節が不要です)。

ここからは推測ですが、質問者さんの[以前のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44262/19110)に載っていたコードでは今回のものと比べて一段深く if がネストしており、当該の `return False` にあたる部分が意味を持っていました。もし今回のコードが前回のものを参考にしたものであるなら、こういった経緯で打ち間違えたのではないかと予想します。

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます！