# クラスの引数・変数・変数の参照についての質問です。

Tags: python

参考書内で”戦争”と呼ばれるゲームのコードを作っていた際の質問です。
該当ページ、辞書として用いている参考書、ネットの情報を参照しても不明点が解決せず、これ以上考えるのはあまりよくないと思い質問させていただきます。
初歩的な質問だとは思いますが、これを機にクラスへの理解を深めたいです。

コードが長いため、下に掲載します。

①Cardクラスのスイート、２・３番目のメソッド
`__lt__`,`__gt__`の引数である`c2`がどこでこのメソッドに渡されているのかわかりません。
なので、ここのif文にあるc2.valueがどこから引っ張ってこられているのか全く分かりません。

②,③（おそらく同類の質問）
Gameクラスのスイート、４番目のメソッド
whileループの中２番目のif文の`self.p1.wins`の参照の仕方について
☆☆☆を参照する際にwinsにselfをつけなくてもいいのですか？

同クラス、５番目のメソッド
ここでの２つのif文returnに渡す変数はselfをつけてもつけなくてもよいのですか？
書いているようにselfつけてもつけなくても正常に動きはしました。

参考書では、参照する際にはselfをつけるように記載されていたので少々混乱しています。

コードです。

```
class Card:
    suits=["spades","hearts","diamonds","clubs"]

    values=[None,None,
            "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
            "10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace"]


    def __init__(self,v,s):
        """スート・マークはともにint型オブジェクトで扱います"""
        self.value=v
        self.suit=s

    def __lt__(self,c2): #__lt__は比較用の特殊メソッドです（より小さい）
        #c2がどこで作られるオブジェクトなのかわかってません。
        #でも、__lt__ or __gt__メソッドが呼ばれればその時の引数に渡せばいい。え、でもそれもどこ？ｗｗ
        if self.value<c2.value:
            return True
        if self.value==c2.value:
            if self.suit<c2.suit:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        return False

    def __gt__(self,c2): #__gt__は比較用の特殊メソッドです（より大きい）
        if self.value>c2.value:
            return True
        if self.value==c2.suit:
            return True
            if self.suit>c2.suit:
                    return True
            else:
                    return False

    def __repr__(self):
        v=self.values[self.value]+" of "+self.suits[self.suit]
        return v

from random import shuffle #意味をきちんと言えるようにしましょう。

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards=[]
        for i in range(2,15): #トランプの５２枚のカードを用意しています。
            for j in range(4):
                self.cards.append(Card(i,j))
        shuffle(self.cards)

    def rm_card(self):
        if len(self.cards)==0: #カードの枚数が０になると終わりです。
            return
        return self.cards.pop() #引くカードの被りを避けています。

"""
deck=Deck()
for card in deck.cards: #参照の仕方をきちんと覚えましょう。
    print(card)

このコードによりトランプが正確に出力されるか確認しました。
また、ここまでのエラーに直結する要素は全て解決されています。
"""

class Player: #後で使うための下準備です。
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.wins=0 #☆☆☆
        self.card=None
        self.name=name

class Game: #これ、”ここ”でDeck呼び出してるけど、継承した時との違いは？
    def __init__(self):
        name1=input("プレイヤー１の名前 ")
        name2=input("プレイヤー２の名前 ")
        self.deck=Deck() #ここ
        #上はDeckクラスのオブジェクトとしてカードをdeckのセルフ変数に参照しています。
        self.p1=Player(name1)
        self.p2=Player(name2)

    def wins(self,winner):
        w="このラウンドは{}が勝ちました"
        w=w.format(winner) #winsメソッドの引数winnerが上の{}に追加されます。
        print(w)

    def draw(self,p1n,p1c,p2n,p2c): #それぞれのプレイヤーが引いたカードをコールします。
        d="{}は{}、{}は{}を引きました。"
        d=d.format(p1n,p1c,p2n,p2c)
        print(d)

    def play_game(self):
        cards=self.deck.cards #Deckクラスのself.deckオブジェクトを引数としてDeckクラス内のcardsメソッドに渡します。
        print("Let's begin the game called war!")
        while len(cards)>=2:
            m="qで終了、それ以外のキーでPlay:"
            response=input(m)
            if response=="q":
                break
            p1c=self.deck.rm_card()
            p2c=self.deck.rm_card()
            p1n=self.p1.name
            p2n=self.p2.name
            self.draw(p1n,p1c,p2n,p2c)
            if p1c>p2c:
                self.p1.wins+=1 #これ、☆☆☆を参照しているのだろうけどwinsにselfはいらない？
                self.wins(self.p1.name)
            else:
                self.p2.wins+=1
                self.wins(self.p2.name)

        win=self.winner(self.p1,self.p2)
        print("ゲーム終了、{}の勝利です！".format(win))
    def winner(self,p1,p2):
        if p1.wins>p2.wins:
            return self.p1.name #元はp1.nameだったけど、self変数にしなくていいのか迷ったのでいったんself変数で書いてます。
        if p1.wins<p2.wins:
            return p2.name
        return "引き分け" #elseの処理これでもできるんだっけ、覚えてないです。


game=Game()
game.play_game()
```

P.S.
＃は自分がコードを書いている際に思ったことなどを書いています。
質問したところ以外にも疑問点を書いていますが、自分でまだ十分にしらべられてないので
もし、調べてわからなければもう一度追加質問させていただきます。
また、どこが原因なのかわからないため、全体を掲載します。ご容赦ください。
質問該当箇所はわかりやすく記したつもりではありますが、わかりにくい点があればご指摘ください。

Comment: Word使ってTabで一括インデントしたんですが、あれって空白１文字として認識されないのですね・・・

Comment: うまく表示する方法がわかりません・・・

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　コード部分の装飾についてですが、普通にコードをコピー＆ペーストした後、コード部分をマウスカーソルで範囲選択し、エディタ上部の `{}` を押すと自動的にコードブロックとして装飾することができます。その他より詳しい装飾の方法については[こちらのヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)に書かれておりますので、必要に応じてご参照ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！編集いたしました。

Comment: ①のご質問については、こちらの質問と重複していそうです: [クラスの関数で、self 以外の変数が何なのか分からない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44262/19110)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ① `__lt__(self, c2)` の `c2` とは何か？

`<` で比較するときの右側の引数です。こちらの別質問をご覧ください: [「クラスの関数で、self 以外の変数が何なのか分からない」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44262/19110)

#### ② `self.p1.wins += 1` の `wins` に `self` はつけなくて良い？

つけません。

`self` は自分自身のことを示す特別なオブジェクトなのでした。また、`self.p1` もオブジェクトであり、`Game` クラスのインスタンス変数 `p1` のことを指しています。

つまりこの行では「`Game` クラスのインスタンス変数 `p1`」のインスタンス変数 `wins` を操作しようとしているのです。`self.p1` の時点でどのオブジェクトの `wins` を操作しようとしているのか明らかです。

また、`self` という名前は同じですが、`Game` クラスのメソッドの中で使われる `self` は `Game` クラスのオブジェクトそのものを指しており、`Player` クラスのオブジェクトを指しているわけではないことにも注意してください。

#### ③ 関数 `winner(self, p1, p2)` において `self.p1` と `p1` に差はある？

少なくとも `self.p1` と `p1` に差はあります。

`self.p1` は自分自身がインスタンス変数として持っている `p1` を指す一方、`p1` は関数 `winner` の引数として与えられた `p1` を指します。

「`self` をつけてもつけなくても同じように動作した」とのことですが、これは `play_game()` 関数の中で `winner` 関数を呼び出す際に以下のようにしているからです。

```
win = self.winner(self.p1, self.p2)
```

上のように使う限りは、`p1` と `self.p1` が一致するため、`self` があってもなくても同じ動作になります。(蛇足: このような使い方しかしないのであれば、`winner` 関数の引数 `p1`, `p2` は不要だと思われます。書籍中の別の箇所で違う使い方をするのかもしれません。)

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: ①に関して、リンク先拝見しました。

Comment: >試しに Card クラスのインスタンスを作って比較してみると分かりやすいです。
とのことなのですが、このコードでc2というインスタンスが明示的に作られていないと思うのですが、インスタンスを明示的に作らなくても比較可能なのでしょうか？(なにか勘違いしている気が‥)

Comment: @u_1 さん、すいません、おっしゃっている意味が理解できませんでした。何か誤解されていると思います。あてずっぽうでアドバイスすると、`__lt__` の引数 `c2` は `Card` のインスタンス変数ではなく、単に関数の引数です。

Comment: @u_1 質問文中にあるコードですと、`Deck` クラス内の `self.cards.append(Card(i,j))` という行で `Card` クラスのインスタンスを作っています。

Comment: えぇと、、、引数であることは理解しており、`self.cards.append(Card(i,j))`でCardクラスのインスタンスを生成しているところまでは大丈夫なのですが

Comment: この、__lt__,__gt__メソッドは後のGameクラスのplay_gameメソッドの`p1c>p2c:`という比較をする際に必要だから、作ったと思っています。

Comment: で、その際にp1cは`p1c=self.deck.rm_card()`と`rm_card`が実行されており、「大小比較の__lt__,__gt__が実行されてなくない？」ということが疑問です。

Comment: たびたび申し訳ございません、わかりにくければ再度ご指摘いただけると幸いです・・

Comment: @u_1 さん、`rm_card` 関数は実行されるとデッキの中から 1 枚カードを選んで返り値としています。したがって `p1c` は `Card` クラスのインスタンスです。よって `p1c > p2c` では `Card` クラスの `__gt__` 関数が実行されています。

Comment: あ、わかった気がします！そもそも特殊メソッドというものは参照する、というより演算子を使ったら自動で参照されるものなのですね・・？

Comment: `rm_card()`と同様に__lt__だって`self.（変数）.__lt__()`がないといけないのでは？と思っていました

Comment: @u_1 はい、そのとおりです :) `a < b` は `a.__lt__(b)` を呼び出します。詳しくは[こちらのドキュメント](https://docs.python.jp/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)に書かれています。

Comment: それ、読んだんですがいまいち意味が分かってなかったようです。（やっとわかりました！！）

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Comment: @u_1 解決したようで良かったです。よければ回答左のチェックマークから[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)して頂けると僕が嬉しいです :)

Comment: 何度もありがとうございます！また、質問があればよろしくお願いします。